# Unable to download buildkit on ubuntu

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit

On a fresh Ubuntu system when running the command

> curl -Ls https://civicrm.org/get-buildkit.sh | bash -s -- --full --dir ~/buildkit

as requested on the document on the repository, i get the following error

> bash: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>   bash: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

and the download fails to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussed this a bit over Mattermost. For debugging this, it made sense to run the first half of the command and check the output, e.g.

```
curl -Ls https://civicrm.org/get-buildkit.sh
```

It should display a bash script. However, it actually displayed an error message about an IP restriction. A quick work-around was to download the script through a different URL, i.e.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/master/bin/civi-download-tools | bash -s -- --full --dir ~/buildkit
```

Comment: for users of Ubuntu variants such as ** elamentary ** be sure to change the distribution code name using export DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty